# SmartTarget Region and Query relationship?

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

Per the [SDL SmartTarget 2014 documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-2E35D309-1457-48BA-A591-AE1E2BABA8BA), `tcdl` **queries** appear in **regions**.

```
<tcdl:region>
  <tcdl:query>
   <tcdl:facet />
   <tcdl:item />    
   <tcdl:search />
   <tcdl:attribute />
   <tcdl:promotions />
   <tcdl:navigation />
  <tcdl:items />                                
 </tcdl:query>
</tcdl:region>
```

Example:

```
<tcdl:region id="Sidebar" type="SmartTarget"> 
  <tcdl:query publication='tcm:0-1-1'> 
    <tcdl:facet category='tcm:1-3-4' /> 
    <tcdl:promotions region='Sidebar' maxItems='5'> 
    ...
    </tcdl:promotions> 
</tcdl:query>
```

**What's the (ordinal) relationship between regions and queries?**

1. Is it a 1:1 (one-to-one) relationship?
2. If not, does each region *need* a query?
3. Must a query appear within a region (i.e. can queries be added elsewhere on a page?
4. In the example, does the `Sidebar` in `<tcdl:promotions region='Sidebar' maxItems='5'>` represent the `Sidebar` id in `<tcdl:region id="Sidebar" type="SmartTarget">`?

For SmartTarget functional requirements I think we can document region and query requirements together, but I want to be sure.

If regions always have a query, then at least functionally, a region would be:

- Name (Id)
- Publication
- Allow Duplicates (Y/N)
- Timeout (milliseconds)
- <strike>View</strike> (not supported, but would be one of: lister, detail, search, home, summary, compare)
- Redirect (T/F)

*Plus additional SmartTarget functionality for that region (e.g. search, navigation, promotions, etc).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queries are independent of regions and can appear outside of them; but the TBBs will only support adding them to regions. That's mostly because there are not many ways to programmatically determine where in the HTML to place something -- so it requires you to mark those areas with a region for easy access.

You can have multiple regions with Promotions inside a single query. In fact, it is recommended to have a single query per web page if at all possible.

Typically when using the TBBs that would mean having a "query region" on the outside (say, immediately inside the body element in the HTML) and one or more Promotion regions on the inside. A "query region" would not need to be available for Promotions, so you don't need to have them in your configuration -- they just need to be in the template output.

As for your 4th question: yes, Sidebar means the same thing in all of those cases.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. So in that example setup, the `id` for the query region only really matters for the `Add SmartTarget Query TBB`, right? The documentation examples happen to re-use the same id, but I could have say three (independent) regions: one for the ST query, one for say "sidebar" promotions, and another for "bottom" promotions?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.

Comment: Good Q&A, cause this separation between region and query is not documented afaik.